# how would i skip displaying certain entries when populating cell rows from core data in a tableviewcontroller?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

For an app I'm working on, i have saved several items to my coredata model.

My intention is to selectively print them out to a tableview based on whether certain attributes are true.

Example given the items in CoreData:

/////////////////////

1--name: Joe, display: true

2--name: Sally, display:false

3--name: Bob, display:false

4--name: Jess, display:true

/////////////////////

i would only want my table view to display to cells where display is true
so out of the 4 entries only Joe and Jess would be listed in my tableview

So far, I only know how to print out every single item. with the table view datasource protocol

thanks for helping out a noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

// Your Entity here is called "Users"

```
var myUsers = [Users]()

var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
let Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "display = %@", true)

fetchRequest.predicate = Predicate
// maybe Sort?    
var sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "UserID", ascending: true)
var sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

myUsers = context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Users]
```

// use them in your TableView (cellForRowAtIndexPath)

```
var myuser = myUsers[indexPath.row] as Users
```

Comment: thanks for also showing how it would fit into the context of things like sorting and executefetchrequest

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the Core Data objects in a 
table view.

Restricting the displayed items is then simply done by setting a predicate

```
NSPredicate(format: "display == YES")
```

on the fetched results controller.